# Commemorating the 10th Anniversary of this site

Tags: discussion

The Pi just turned 10 years old. This site will turn 10 on the 9th of June (IIRC). Is anything planned to commemorate? Should we do something to commemorate this milestone? Some ideas:

- live stream (showing off projects),
- AMA,
- some type of giveaway,
- a retrospective meta post.

Does StackExchange mark the anniversary in some fashion?

Comment: I was hoping for a little more input from the community tbh.

Comment: @Ghanima honestly so was I.

Comment: Please feel free to give some input over here: [Commemorating the 10th Anniversary of the Raspberry Pi Stack - We need your input for Stack Exchange's upcoming Blog post](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/commemorating-the-10th-anniversary-of-the-raspberry-pi-stack-we-need-your-inpu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, SE doesn't mark anniversaries. In fact, it's been like pulling teeth to get them to graduate sites from Beta. RPi.SE has it good in that there's a site design (which is crazy rare). Most sites will never get even that.

What I would suggest is doing your #4 yourself: make a retrospective Meta post. A moderator can then tag it [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (as this post currently is) and others can read, upvote, etc. For comparison, that's [mostly what SciFi.SE did](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13249/62709).

Comment: That's not entirely true, SE actually does mark the ten year anniversaries see https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/16/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-site-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-q1-2022/ and ... spoilers ... we will be up next. CC @SteveRobillard

Comment: Yeah, leave it to SE to make me a liar a week after I post this :P