# Commemorating the 10th Anniversary of the Raspberry Pi Stack - We need your input for Stack Exchange's upcoming Blog post

Tags: discussion, announcement

As has been pointed out by Steve [before](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2311/19949), we are commemorating the 10th Anniversary of this site. We have been asked by SE for a brief summary to be featured in SE's blog, see the [previous entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/16/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-site-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-q1-2022/) for a look'n'feel.

We would like to ask you, the users of this community, to contribute to this short text, just a few lines after all. We are also interested in your take on the additional features, such as a few "interesting questions" that highlight our site, e.g.

- Most upvoted question or
- Interesting questions
- Most popular tag
- (something completely different?)

The final text is required by May 18th, but please feel free to give your input at your earliest convenience to allow for community feedback.

Thanks, y'all.

Comment: Most used (and totally meaningless) tag "raspbian"

Comment: @Milliways and that is why we might choose to deviate from the default setting of "most used" tag to something we might deem useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following as "interesting". [can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5427/8697)

While not currently the best solution the answers are highly informative.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Milliways.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any other input; Another "interesting" suggestion. [A Brief History of … Raspberry Pi OS](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/a-brief-history-of-raspberry-pi-os)